# How to plot some edges with OSMX?

Tags: julia, openstreetmap, folium

I have a subset of edges from `m.e` which does not necessarily form a path and I wan to visualize them.

```
Edges =[(42448558, 42448549)
 (1918039864, 42432082)
 (42445543, 42445548)
 (42429754, 486869282)
 (486869282, 42429754)
 (4321748238, 4321748237)
 (42437114, 4202950102)
 (42437608, 42437114)
 (1773076514, 1773076511)]
```

I've tried to visualize it but in converting this node ids to LLA coordinates it throw a Key error `bounds not found`. How to fix this?

```
flm = pyimport("folium")
matplotlib_cm = pyimport("matplotlib.cm")
matplotlib_colors = pyimport("matplotlib.colors")

cmap = matplotlib_cm.get_cmap("prism")


mf = flm.Map()
for k=1: length(links_o )
    locs = [LLA(n,m.bounds) for n in links_o[k]]
    flm.PolyLine(        
        [(loc.lat, loc.lon) for loc in locs ],
        popup=info,
        tooltip=info,
        color=matplotlib_colors.to_hex(cmap(k/SHOW_PATHS))       
    ).add_to(mf)
end

MAP_BOUNDS = [(m.bounds.min_y,m.bounds.min_x),(m.bounds.max_y,m.bounds.max_x)]
flm.Rectangle(MAP_BOUNDS, color="black",weight=6).add_to(mf)
mf.fit_bounds(MAP_BOUNDS)
mf
```